# Remove image size by screen size

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to know if there is some way that I can remove the image width and height when my screen resolution is lower than 980px? Through a jquery or something?

Image like this:

```
<img width="477" height="299" src="/uploads/2012/01/415.jpg" class="attachment-portfolio2 wp-post-image"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: You've tagged media-queries. Looks like thats all you'll need for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Are you thinking below IE9? else media queries will do.

Comment: How do you mean 'remove'? As in force them to occupy all available width? Removing the width and height will cause them to revert to their original size... Also, screen resolution isn't measured in pixels, I assume you mean screen width?

Comment: Yes i want the original size, i need remove the width and height from html tag. i cannot use media querie css

Comment: @Chead - In that case the `media-queries` tag is mis-leading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method:

```
var images;

$(function() {  
    images = $('img.wp-post-image');
    removeSize();
});

$(window).resize(removeResize);

function removeSize()
{
    if($(window).width() < 980 && images.length > 0)
    {
        images.removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer and should be marked as so.
the only thing I might do differently is what happens inside your if statement. I know that the OP asked how to remove the height/width of the image but imo that seems like a poor solution as opposed to setting the height/width to either auto, or a calculated value. letting it revert to default seems hackish as you aren't truly manipulating the element

Comment: I know, but the OP wants the image to return to default. See his comments.

Comment: i know i read it but that doesn't mean he knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following CSS:

```
/* for all screens in general */
.wp-post-image {
   width: 477px;
   height: 299px;
}

/* specifically for screens smaller than (or equal to) 980px */    
/* make sure this comes *after* the general rule */
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .wp-post-image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  } 
}
```

Comment: this will work it would seem. a programmatic approach would be to declare the height/width in css and in javascript change those values to auto upon the screen becoming smaller than 980. bind the .resize() event on the window and make the callback function check the current width and upon it becoming smaller, use .css() to change the width and height values to auto or whatever you want.